# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddSeconds(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into

Tags: linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I receive this error on

```
base {System.SystemException} = {"LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime AddSeconds(Double)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."}
```

on this code

```
      var eventToPushCustom = eventCustomRepository.FindAllEventsCustomByUniqueStudentReference(userDevice.UniqueStudentReference)
                                    .Where(x => x.DateTimeStart > currentDateTime && currentDateTime >= x.DateTimeStart.AddSeconds(x.ReminderTime))
                                    .Select(y => new EventPushNotification
                                    {
                                        Id = y.EventId,
                                        EventTitle = y.EventTitle,
                                        DateTimeStart = y.DateTimeStart,
                                        DateTimeEnd = y.DateTimeEnd,
                                        Location = y.Location,
                                        Description = y.Description,
                                        DeviceToken = y.UsersDevice.DeviceTokenNotification
                                    });
```

I believe the problem is in  `x.DateTimeStart.AddSeconds(x.ReminderTime)`

The argument of .AddSeconds in my case must be "dynamic" ... Any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use [EntityFunctions.AddSeconds](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.addseconds.aspx) method to create date time on server side.

```
 .Where(x => x.DateTimeStart > currentDateTime && 
             currentDateTime >= EntityFunctions.AddSeconds(x.DateTimeStart, x.ReminderTime))
```

Comment: Note that EntityFunctions is now obsolete. Use `DbFunctions` instead.

Comment: @TylerForsythe thanks for update! It's a fast-changing world :)

Comment: {"FUNCTION db.AddMinutes does not exist"}  :(

Comment: @Pažout are you using MySQL database?

Comment: @ Tyler Forsythe ,which version of entity framework is needed for using `DbFunctions` ?