# DateTime.Compare in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to use DateTime.Compare in Linq :

```
from ---  
where DateTime.Compare(Convert.ToDateTime(ktab.KTABTOM), DateTime.Now) < 1
select new 
{
-------
}
```

But this gives me an error :

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime ConvertTimeFromUtc(System.DateTime, System.TimeZoneInfo)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14583254/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-datetime-addsecondsdoubl) link suggests that we should use EntityFunctions to fix dateTime manipulation in Linq. But here I need to compare the complete date. Even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15264319/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-timespan-subtractsystem) won't help me.

The date is in format yyyy-MM-dd.

Comment: Why are you storing date information in your database as a string? The reason you don't do that is to avoid problems like this.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain : KTABTOM is nullable DateTime. Plus I don't have control on the database. I will suggest this to concerned people. But can you provide a solution for this as of now?

Comment: if `ktab.KTABTOM` is a nullable DateTime why do you call `Convert.ToDateTime` and not compare it directly?  also do you want NULL's to be included in the results?

Comment: Because if you are comparing nullable and non nullable values, you need to cast.

Comment: @Nitish it is `LINQ to entities` so your query will be translated into sql so there is no need to cast

Comment: Then there is a build error.

Comment: you don't need `DateTime.Compare` just write `ktab.KTABTOM < DateTime.Now`

Comment: @Nitish and `Compare` has next returns: `Less than zero - t1 is earlier than t2.`, `Zero - t1 is the same as t2.`, `Greater than zero - t1 is later than t2.` What are you trying to achieve by comparing result with `1`?

Comment: @Guru he is trying to get dates less than or equal to "now".

Comment: @ErenErsönmez wouldn't it be `<= 0` or i need a lot of more coffee right now?

Comment: @Guru same difference :)

Comment: @ErenErsönmez yeah) forgot that `Compare` returns `int`, thanks)

Comment: @ErenErsönmez in first comment OP has said that KTABTOM is nullable `DateTime`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need `DateTime.Compare` just write `ktab.KTABTOM <= DateTime.Now`

**Examples with nullable DateTime:**

doesn't compile

```
from p in Projects
where DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, p.EndDate) <= 0
select p.EndDate
```

and

```
from p in Projects
where DateTime.Now <= p.EndDate
select p.EndDate
```

translates into

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[EndDate] AS [EndDate]
FROM [dbo].[Project] AS [Extent1]
WHERE  CAST( SysDateTime() AS datetime2) <= [Extent1].[EndDate]
```

**Examples without nullable DateTime:**

```
from p in Projects
where DateTime.Compare(DateTime.Now, p.StartDate) <= 0
select p.StartDate
```

and

```
from p in Projects
where DateTime.Now <= p.StartDate
select p.StartDate
```

both translates into

```
SELECT 
[Extent1].[StartDate] AS [StartDate]
FROM [dbo].[Project] AS [Extent1]
WHERE (SysDateTime()) <= [Extent1].[StartDate]
```

Comment: Bear in mind that in .NET, comparing DateTime directly will ignore time zones, and count only ticks, so that if the DateTimes are not both in the same time zone, the comparison will be wrong.